# LCARS GUI where to start

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, wxpython

Hey so I'm looking to build a star trek GUI (LCARS). To do this, essentially I need to be able to create images (PNGs) and have them act as a button - I would have a "shade" method/function for events such as mouseOver clicked...etc.

What toolkit? or GTK/wxPython would be easiest for this? I would prefer to have a builder.

eventualy I'd like to build something like [this](http://conceptmodeler.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/ingr_lcars_sovereign.jpg)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCARS

Comment: something like this: http://conceptmodeler.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/ingr_lcars_sovereign.jpg (LCARS type of thing)

Comment: @David Heffernan: Unlabeled lights and buttons, of course: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_XNPD380IpBQ/SGq10zQi30I/AAAAAAAABhw/cDEAC3mAcZI/s400/P50_3_ScienceStation.jpg

Comment: LCARS Guidelines  http://www.bracercom.com/tutorial/content/CoherentLCARSInterface/LCARSCoherentInterface.html

Comment: WHOOOAAA!!  Way too geeky for me, I'm outta here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use wxPython's [BitmapButton](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BitmapButton-class.html). You can provide images for focused, disabled, selected, and mouse hover states. There are also fancy button controls that are documented in the wxPython demo.